# My JavaScript slider work fine in the beginning and then it get corrupted

Tags: javascript

My JavaScript slider worked fine in the beginning and then it get corrupted after time,  sometimes it takes one minutes, sometimes it takes five.

Actually I don't know if it is a conflict or what, could you please help me guys?

you can check it out here: http://test-code.bugs3.com/

Comment: The console are showing 'Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <' Remove: "&#8211;" at your title tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When looking at the code it seems you do not yet have much web development skills. That is fine, and thereby I will go through each step of improving your webpage, as I want you to become a great developer too.

First, lets start with some CSS things. Instead of setting the padding for every side, you can also set it on all sides without needing four lines. Simply using `padding:0;` is enough in this case. For the margin, when you want the left and right sides to be auto, and the top and bottom 0px, you can 'chain' them in one property: `margin:top right bottom left;`, like a clock. Even shorter is `margin:top&bottom left&right;`, which in your case is `margin:0 auto;` <-- the top and bottom have 0 margin and the sides have auto margin. (btw if something is 0 you don't need to add a unit to it).

For a border  I found this:

```
border: solid;
border-width: thick;
border-color: #E6E6E6;
```

You can also put that together by using `border:thick solid #E6E6E6;`

Now for the javascript. The problem that it is slow is because it uses a lot of timers and intervals to do things, and the timers do not get cleared well. My opacity is currently at -850. Instead of improving the code I suggest we rewrite it. You have written the same code over and over again for every picture, where only some variable names differ. What if we just write that code once? Would be a lot faster. And we could add as many pictures as we want.

To be able to instantly get a list of all the picture elements, I add a class to them: `class="sliderPicture"`. Now when I want the list I can call `document.getElementsByClassName('sliderPicture');` and there we have our array (I removed the ID's as we won't need em). We also need a variable to keep track of at which picture we are right now. I will elaborate on this later.

As we do not want the animation to be done by using javascript but just by using CSS, we are going to add some css code to the `sliderPicture` class:

```
.sliderPicture {
    opacity:0; /*We want all images to be transparent, as we override this value when we want to display the picture*/
    position:absolute; /*this puts all the pictures in the same place behind eachother, so that we do not need to display:none; and display:block; them*/
    transition:2s opacity; /*this means, every time the opacity of the element changes, do not directly set it to that opacity but fade to it in 2 seconds*/
}
```

Now we create a class which will show the images. The script then only needs to add/remove the class:

```
.showPicture{
    opacity:1;
}
```

Now on to the javascript code. It is pretty short, and I hope the comments explain good enough:

```
var images = document.getElementsByClassName('sliderPicture'); //this contains an array of all the images.
var imageTime = 3000; //the time in ms for when the pictures should change
var i = 0; //the picture we are at
setInterval(function(){
    if(images[i].classList.contains('showPicture')) images[i].classList.remove('showPicture'); //if the element contains the class showPicture, remove it. (we first check for it to not generate errors when removing something that might not be there (it should, but never create any room for errors))
    i++; //increment the image where we are at
        if(i >= images.length) i=0; //if we are at the end of our array. Picture 2 of the array is the last picture, so, as we increment it above, our i value should be 3 then. The length of our array is also 3, so when i=length of the array we set it back to 0 to display the image
    images[i].classList.add('showPicture'); //here we add the class so the element gets opacity 1
}, imageTime);
```

as we want the first picture to directly show up we just add `showPicture` to its class.

I also see nice buttons on the bottom. I think you want them to automatically switch to the picture. I can help you with automatically generating buttons to not have to bother about adding them manually.

Furthermore, if this slider is to display many different images, you can also write a little script to add the images from an array containing the url's. Then you don't need to add `<img class="sliderPicture" src="..." />` every time, but let the javascript generate that for you (including generating the buttons.

All this code is combined in [**this jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/86E56/1/).

If you have a question, any at all, feel free to ask them. I hope you enjoyed reading this answer and have a better understanding on how to combine css and javacript to generate nice webpages.

old:

<strike>this looks like a problem with all the intervals and clearing of things. your code does even look like it can be made much simpeler, as you are using timers to fade things, instead of css. For this fading you can use [transitions](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_transitions.asp). For the condition code, you'd better use an array and take the next item from it (or 0 if there is no next item).</strike>

Comment: hey MarijnS95 thx for answer
can you give me an example for how to use array in my script

Comment: Hi, I wanted to give you an example but my battery died. I will write one within a couple minutes. It will be pretty helpful of you'd put all your code in a jsfiddle for better editing (as proper questions 'should' include code and not say well find the code somewhere here on this link in your console).

Comment: @samehsayed I would like to mention that if you find my answer helpful you should accept it, so other users can easily recognize wether this answer was helpful.